# Windows Forms Custom Control not painting correctly

Tags: c#, winforms, transparency

So i'm trying to make a nice rounded switch that when clicked it will slide either left or right to basically turn something on or off (it could be used for other things). I have a rectangle version working somewhat ok (i have a few tweaks in mind that I want to make for it) but the problem I'm running into is by using rounded rectangles. I made a few classes to help my self in this. I have one called RoundRectanglePath. Using the Create method I give it a Rectangle (or x,y,w,h) and a radius for the corners and it returns a closed GraphicsPath that I can then use Graphics.[Fill|Draw]Path with. I then have a RoundRectangle class which is a just a control that acts very similar to a Label. I found that if I override the OnPaintBackground and not send the event to the base, but instead paint a rectangle the same color as it's Parent.BackColor than I get the illusion that the control is really round. (as a related side note I allow transparent)

For my RoundMovableSwitch class I use 2 RoundRectanglePaths to split the Control in half. The left is a green Color and the right is Pink (thinking about it now I could have just used a horizontal LinearGradient brush...ooops oh well) I then draw the string On and Off on opposing sides. To that control I add a RoundRectangle. When the user clicks on either the RoundRectangle or the MoveableSwitch the Control then moves the RoundRectangle left or right 1 pixel at a time. The movement works great. The problem I am having is this. The outside Edge of the RoundRectangle is the correct Transparent color. The inside edge is the wrong color. See RoundMovingSwitch 1 and 2 in picture below. Once I get the code working correctly I'll go back and reorganize the code a bit more.

[image: Example of problem]

The code is hosted on GitHub: [Here](https://github.com/immeraufdemhund/RoundControls)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"The problem I am having is this. The outside Edge of the RoundRectangle is the correct Transparent color. The inside edge is the wrong color."

Not sure I understand the problem...

Are you trying to get rid of the blue corners that are outside the rounded edges?

If so, then try this in RoundRectangle:
[image]

```
    public RoundRectangle()
    {
        this.ResizeRedraw = true;
        this.VisibleChanged += new EventHandler(RoundRectangle_VisibleChanged);
    }

    private bool RegionSet = false;
    void RoundRectangle_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Visible && !RegionSet)
        {
            RegionSet = true;
            var r = new RectangleEx(this.ClientRectangle);
            var path = RoundRectanglePath.Create(r.ToRectangle(), this.Radius, this.Corners);
            this.Region = new Region(path);
        }
    }
```

*If the size of the control changes then you should reset the Region() property to the new size.

Edit: To make it reset the Region when the size changes:

```
    protected override void OnSizeChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnSizeChanged(e);
        var r = new RectangleEx(this.ClientRectangle);
        var path = RoundRectanglePath.Create(r.ToRectangle(), this.Radius, this.Corners);
        this.Region = new Region(path);
    }
```

Comment: The picture you show is what i am trying to achieve. The problem does not appear to be when the RoundRectangle size changes... but I'll try anything :)